# passing a NSArray to NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c

I would like to pass a NSArray containing NSstrings to NSURLRequest, is it possible ? I'm not quite sure how to approach this, I'm getting it to work fine with just one URL but I can't seem to be able to pass an Array or urls . Any ideas ?

This is the code I'm using which is obviously wrong calling url1, I would like to call an array instead :

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
NSString *url1 = @"http://www.apple.com/";
NSString *url2 = @"http://www.google.com/";

urls = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:url1,url2,nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url1];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to load multiple webpages, right?

```
urls = [[NSArray alloc] initwithObjects:url1, url2, nil];
for (NSURL *url in urls) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

However, I'm not sure why you would want to do this? This may send a request to `url1`, but will instantly cancel that request and start loading `url2`.

Comment: That's working thanks, I would like an url array because I would like to feed to the Leaves code (https://github.com/brow/leaves), I`m updating the question ..